# Stop table cells from overlapping HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am trying to set up a responsive table where each cell contains an image but with the code I have, the cells overlap.

Widths are set to 100% rather than fixed width so not sure why this is happening? The code that I have is below:

```css
.infocard {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.infocard img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.infocard .infocardimage {
  z-index: 9999;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.infocard:hover .infocardimage {
  opacity: 0;
}

.tableproperties {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table class="tableproperties">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="infocard">
          <img alt="" class="infocardimage" src="https://animatedanatomy.com/images/16-9-dummy-image6.jpg" />
          <img alt="" class="infocardoverlay" src="http://barricadeprinters.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/16-9placeholder.png" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="infocard">
          <img alt="" class="infocardimage" src="https://animatedanatomy.com/images/16-9-dummy-image6.jpg" />
          <img alt="" class="infocardoverlay" src="http://barricadeprinters.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/16-9placeholder.png" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="infocard">
          <img alt="" class="infocardimage" src="https://animatedanatomy.com/images/16-9-dummy-image6.jpg" />
          <img alt="" class="infocardoverlay" src="http://barricadeprinters.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/16-9placeholder.png" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="infocard">
          <img alt="" class="infocardimage" src="https://animatedanatomy.com/images/16-9-dummy-image6.jpg" />
          <img alt="" class="infocardoverlay" src="http://barricadeprinters.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/16-9placeholder.png" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need the rows to not overlap when the screen is resized and the gap to not get bigger when the screen is made smaller.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any code at the page you referenced. Please include relevant code in your post to provide a [working demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue.

Comment: I have added the code snippet however the preview doesn't appear the same as on my builder

Comment: This may require some troubleshooting on your part to identify what might be different between the code in your builder and the code you've provided here. For example, are you loading any additional style sheets other than what's shown here?

Comment: I can't seem to see why it was displaying differently, may be something to do with the builder I was using. I have since decided against using a physical table to lay out the images as I am told that this is much more favourable design. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can i suggest you to update a bit your sources of information about the layout best practices? Table are only for data display and should not be used for laying out objects on the page (we are no more in the '90s). And they are exactly the opposite of what you need to achieve responsiveness

Comment: Lelio, you’re right, I know- my coding ability is basic at best. I was instructed ages ago on another site that using a table would work and have wrongly stuck with it ever since. You’ll be glad to know that the solution I found did not use any tables! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the img + img selector into the css along with the accompanying html:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.card {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
  position:relative;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
.imageoverlay{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.card:hover img + img{
  display:block;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://animatedanatomy.com/images/16-9-dummy-image6.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
    <img class="imageoverlay" src="http://barricadeprinters.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/16-9placeholder.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://animatedanatomy.com/images/16-9-dummy-image6.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
     <img class="imageoverlay" src="http://barricadeprinters.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/16-9placeholder.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://animatedanatomy.com/images/16-9-dummy-image6.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
     <img class="imageoverlay" src="http://barricadeprinters.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/16-9placeholder.png" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://animatedanatomy.com/images/16-9-dummy-image6.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
     <img class="imageoverlay" src="http://barricadeprinters.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/16-9placeholder.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://animatedanatomy.com/images/16-9-dummy-image6.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
     <img class="imageoverlay" src="http://barricadeprinters.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/16-9placeholder.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://animatedanatomy.com/images/16-9-dummy-image6.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
     <img class="imageoverlay" src="http://barricadeprinters.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/16-9placeholder.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad you got it worked out. Please revise your answer to comment on what you changed (or was it just the float clearing?). Don't forget to accept the answer to close out this post. Thanks.